# How to highlight specific dates on a bar chart in R (and label each year on the axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar graph of mortality frequencies each year from 2000-2013. I have two events which occurred in 2003 and 2007, so I would like these years bars to be highlighted a different color. I am currently using ggchart with the following code:

```
spec <- highlight_spec(
  what = c("2003", "2007"),
  highlight_color = "darkorange3"
`enter code here`) 
bar_chart(
  YearMortality,
  Year,
  freq,
  sort = FALSE,
  horizontal = FALSE,
  highlight = spec
)
```

This gives me the chart below.

Frequency of mortality each year from 2000-2013

[image]

The years are numerical values, which I think is why they aren't each appearing as x-axis values. I am not sure how to fix the code to display the x-axis labels, or how I should change the numerical values to characters. Any suggestions?

**Edit: data frame information**

Here is the information recommended by Peter,

```
structure(list(Year = 2000:2013, freq = c(9L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 
9L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: You could set the breaks via `scale_x_continuous`, e.g. `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2005, 2010, 2003, 2007))`.